# Azure cloud service error in Development Fabric when I try to run in my Visual Studio

Tags: azure

When I click the run button in Visual Studio, I stopped getting my solution to work. I checked the Development Fabric and in the status bar, I get the following error:

```
Failed to register logger for deployment
```

This is also strange because we the solution on SVN and my colleague has no problems at all. What does this mean?! And why did this start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damn it! I unloaded the worker role and did not update the cloud service project accordingly! It's solved now.